# Can Vitest UI display coverage report directory?

Tags: vite, vitest

I have a Vite project, and I would like to include Vitest UI. I have added the configuration, plus the coverage report configuration.

Here is the `vite.config`:

```javascript
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: "jsdom",
        include: ["**/*.test.{ts,tsx}"],
        setupFiles: ["./src/test/setup.ts"],
        css: true,
        reporters: ['default', 'html'],
        coverage: {
            reportsDirectory: "html/ui",
            include: ["**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
            exclude: ["src/test/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
            reporter: ['text', ['html', { subdir: 'coverage'}]],
            provider: "v8",
        }
    },
```

When I run

```bash
vitest --ui --coverage.enabled=true
```

the UI appears (`http://localhost:51204/__vitest__/#/?file=`) however I don't see the coverage report button:

[image: current view in vitest ui]

Expected:

[image: expected view in vitest ui]

However, when I run the following command:

```bash
npx vite preview --outDir ./html
```

I do see the coverage report button on the browser, `http://localhost:4173/`

[image: vite preview image]

Is there a way to add the coverage button when running `vitest --ui` or this is not possible? Is it only available on `vite preview`? I've read the docs, and it seems to imply you can have the reports button when running `vitest --ui`. Perhaps I'm missing a configuration somewhere or misunderstanding the docs.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I have this exact same question

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still a mystery; I have moved on from this issue. I hope the community can answer this.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
"test:ui": "vitest --ui --coverage",
```